# Delevering zip file over HTTP response in an AWS TypeScript Lambda attached to API Gateway

Tags: typescript, http, aws-lambda, zip, aws-api-gateway

As the tittle descibes I need to deliver a local zip file over http from an AWS TypeScipt Lambda.

Something a kin to this:

```
exports.handler = async function (event: any) {
   let zip = readZip()
   return {
      statusCode: 200, 
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/zip", "Content-Dispostion": "attachment; filename=filename.zip" }, 
      body: zip
   }
}
```

I have looked the internet over and here is what I have attempted most succesfully for the readZip function:

```
const zipFile = fs.readFileSync("filename.zip", "utf8")
retun zipFile
```

This code yields me a zip file that is 99% similar to the actual one, however the incorrect 1% of characters make it so the file is "corrupt" i.e. un-unzipable.

I have seen other solutions like using JSZip alone or along with JSZipUtils, I have also tried reading the file as a base64 String and then decoding it, as well as reading the file into a byte buffer and then converting it, to no avail.

I need to deliver the actual file as the APIGateway response to the endpoint call, so a download link to the file housed in an s3 bucket does not fit my use case.

Does anyone have any insights on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to put it simply what I did to solve this was:

1. Adding the "'Content-Encoding': 'base64'" header to the request
2. reading the file in base64
3. adding the "isBase64Encoded: true" parameter to the return
4. Also remenber to enable binary content in the ApiGateway or else this will not work

This effectively means that the content is twice base64 encoded once by the read and once by AWS where the lambda encodes and the ApiGateway decodes and it is decoded again in the HTTP Client.

This is how the code looked by the end:

```
exports.handler = async function (event: any) {
   let zip = readZip()
   return {
      statusCode: 200, 
      headers: { 
         "Content-Type": "application/zip, application/octet-stream", 
         "Content-Dispostion": "attachment; filename=filename.zip"
         "Content-Encoding" : "base64"
      },     
      body: zip,
      isBase64Encoded : true
   }
}
```

readZip() function:

```
const zipFile = fs.readFileSync("filename.zip", "base64")
return zipFile
```